# A new language with the new stuff in modern C++, but without the issues of backward compatibility?

Tags: c++

I was seeing this [Herb Sutter talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEx5DNLWGgA). C++ is changing so much, and backward compatibility is becoming such a pain. Wouldn't it be better to just create a NEW language with just the good new stuff of C++, which doesn't have to maintain backward compatibility?

I do not intend to start a flame war here. This is an objective question: Are there any initiatives out there that are trying to create a new language based on the good new features of C++, but forgetting about the backward compatibility?

**On Quora:** http://qr.ae/RS2k2L

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Can you suggest a different forum then? I just want to see if there is a "new C++" project out there.

Comment: This is a subjective question, and probably will be closed pretty soon. Given said that, you can check out Rustlang: https://www.rust-lang.org/

Comment: There are **lots** of languages who tried just that. I just can't remember their names right now because they weren't really successful, were they? :-D ([D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_%28programming_language%29) and [Rust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_%28programming_language%29) spring to mind.)

Comment: @DevSolar Thanks! :P ... Seriously, I realize this question may be subjective. Is there a better place I can learn about these alternative languages?

Comment: One of the absolutely strongest points of C++ is its ability to interact and take on existing C and old C++ code, whilst offering modern powerful concepts for when those are suitable. There are LOTS of projects out there that are well designed and fully supported in C or C++, which are SLOWLY modified to use more C++ features for that reason. Where if you had to do all of it at once, it probably wouldn't happen at all.

Comment: @CompuChip No. Nothing with Garbage Collection qualifies.

Comment: On Quora: http://qr.ae/RS2k2L.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava I know C++ isn't safe. But using the modern features can make your code *safer*.

Comment: @becko that presentation is about C. C++ is a different language with its own set of UBs.

Comment: One of the main "problems" with "replacing" C++ is the huge amount of readily available code, both C and C++. Designing a language that does away with the backward compatibility means abandoning that code base. That's **why** such languages, which might be beautiful to behold in the CS lab, fail at replacing C++. Chicken and egg.

Comment: @DevSolar OK I removed that and here is my comment which should apply: remove undefined behavior from that new language, and it may make sense to think of new language. You pay too much for what undefined behavior gives you in replacement. This is my final comment on this

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava perhaps. but linking a presentation on C to a question about C++ is a step in the wrong direction IMHO.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava The first two examples are fairly trivial, compilers will warn you when returning a reference or address to a local variable, and you can't assign a string literal to a non-`const` `char*` in c++. The third example can be caught with `std::array::at`. The last one, well, that's just bad programming but luckily divide by zero segfaults are easy to catch in the debugger.

Comment: @user657267 there are more examples afterwards

Comment: D is probably the closest you will get.

Comment: (very opinionated) We could also think about implementing a meta-compiler transforming bad style / legacy C and C++ code into beatiful, standard-compliant code... I mean: any language is as clean as the codebase. In C++ you find experts, in new languages, everyone is a newbie and the code quality will be low ;-)